# Optimizing code in react when I need to make a lot of calculations

Tags: react-hooks

I put a little example of my code in React, I need to make a lot of calculations, is there a optimal way to do that?  I want the values change as the values in the state change.

```
    const [data, setData] = useState( 
       a: 30,
       b: 15,
       c: 100,
       d: 50
);
    const [atot, setATot] = useState(data.a * 18);
    const [btot, setBtot] = useState(data.b * d);
    const [ctot, setCtot] = useState(data.c * 20);
    ...... here goes more variables

    useEffect(() => {
        setATot(data.a * 18);
        setBtot(data.b * atot);
        setCtot(data.c * 20);
        ...... here goes more variables
        
    }, [data]);

    return(
          <div>value1: {atot}</div>
          <div>value2: {btot}</div>
          <div>value3: {ctot}</div>
     )
```

Is it a good way to work the code like above?

Answer (score 1):

In your case it's better use [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) hook

```
const initialState = { a: 30,
       b: 15,
       c: 100,
       d: 50
};

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ATot':
      return {...state, a: state.a * action.payload};
    case 'BTot':
      return {...state, b: state.b * action.payload};
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}
```